# JavaFX throwing seemingly-impossible IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, exception, javafx

I know that JavaFX puts heavy restrictions on nodes being added more than once to a given parent. It seems reasonable that the code segment...

```
parent.getChildren().add(node1);
parent.getChildren().add(node1);
```

...will throw an exception on the second call, because the node cannot be included in a parent more than once.

However, my problem is a bit more obscure. The following code comes from within a subclass of Pane.

```
if (this.getChildren().contains(foo)) {
    System.out.println("WARNING" + /* some other info about foo */);
} else {
    System.out.println("all okay");
}
this.getChildren().remove(foo);
this.getChildren().add(foo); // this still throws an exception
```

This is the error log that is printed:

```
all okay
all okay
all okay
...
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Children: duplicate children added: parent = CardList@63eddf37
```

I'm not sure what could possibly be causing this, or if it's potentially a bug in JavaFX. My app doesn't use any multi-threading, and even if it did, JavaFX is very controlling of its thread safety.

If anyone could provide some insight as to what's causing this, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your knowledge about not able to add nodes twice is correct. Nevertheless, it's very difficult to know what exactly is going wrong by the information you have provided. Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for the same?

Comment: @OP, I can imagine, according to the message you post (in thread...) that you most certainly run into a concurrency problem (race condition). Maybe, not sure, your code removes and adds in the same "time fragment", which means, that he maybe tries to add while the GUI tree is still not updated. You can test that by delaying the second ADD call with Platform.runLater(), do that to test and we will see if the guess is partially right, then we can find a nicer solution.

Comment: Did you override `equals` for `foo`?

Comment: Might `foo` be a _grandchild_ of `this`?